# Default Separator of Map Only Job

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop2

How to change the **default key-value separator of a Map Only job in MapReduce paradigm?** It gives the output where key and value from mappers are separated by "\t" but I need to change this separator as ",". Is it possible, without outputting NullWritable for key/value, with Map only job?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following lines in the job definition

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ",");
```

Comment: This configuration is used with hadoop1.x only and it didn't work for me.

Comment: try using mapreduce instead of mapred
    conf.set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", ",");

Comment: I think it is better conf.set(TextOutputFormat.SEPERATOR, ",");